# Where to find source code for native matrix visual in Power BI

Tags: matrix, powerbi

I just want to add the possibility to make the text into the header of the matrix vertical as shown below in the screenshot of my dashboard.

[image]

I think I need to develop a custom visual for that because it is not possible to do that with the native component. For that I need to access the code of the native matrix visual and enrich it with the new property.

I search a lot in google and can't found the source code :(

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Quick Google search says that [the source has been deprecated](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Power-BI-Table-Visual-Source-Code/td-p/196185) (the legacy code links in that post are dead too).

Comment: I know that source code of the Power BI visuals are not public anymore but I was wondering if I could find it somewhere..